# File not found in my eclipse plugin boundle

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am developing my first eclipse plugin. The plugin among the other things performs XSLT transformation, with this code:

```
Bundle bundle = Activator.getDefault().getBundle();
IPath smrlSsPath = new Path("/addins/smrl/smrl4odf2shore.xslt");
URL smrlSsUrl = FileLocator.find(bundle, smrlSsPath, Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
File smrlStylesheet = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(smrlSsUrl).toURI());
xsltSource = new StreamSource(smrlStylesheet);
transFact = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
trans = transFact.newTransformer(xsltSource);
trans.setParameter("smrl.file", smrlFile.getAbsolutePath());
trans.transform(xmlSource, new StreamResult(outputTempFile));
```

File smrl4odf2shore.xslt includes other XSLT files:

```
<xsl:include href="odf2shore.xslt"/>
```

This works fine during development. Unfortunately, when I export plugin and deploy it in eclipse instance the error comes up:

```
ERROR:  'C:\Programy\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\837\1\.cp\addins\smrl\odf2shore.xslt (The system cannot find the file specified)'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet
```

I checked the path specified in error and I found there only file: smrl4odf2shore.xslt. File included within the stylesheet (odf2shore.xslt) was not present there. I have checked the JAR of my plugin within the /plugins/ directory and both files were there, so it seems like the file is missing only from /bundles/ directory (eclipse moved only files mentioned within the code, not within the stylesheet).

Can you tell me please what should I do to make eclipse move all the files from JAR to /boundles/ directory?

Comment: Are you sure you included the files in your `build.properties`?

Comment: Yep, I did it. Still I dont know how to solve the problem, so I added few lines which do nothing but use the problematic file - it caused the file to appear in the bundle.